# How can I find entries that link to a given entry?

Tags: entry

I'm retiring a section of my website and want to remove all existing internal links to this section. Is there an existing way to find any links to each entry in that section?

These links are all in Redactor fields (eg. inserted via the toolbar), and these fields may have different names etc across multiple sections.

I've tried running a regex search across a Craft database dump, looking for a pattern of `{entry:[0-9]+:url}` which shows me all the places that link to other entries, but this alone only gives me the entry IDs so I'll have to write further code to look up those IDs and work out which ones are in the section I'm removing.

Is there an easier way to do this, or is it going to be a semi-manual job?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about running something like Screaming Frog https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/